NextJS util functions randomly failing
I have a web app using NextJS, Prisma, Supabase (recently migrated from PlanetScale), and Clerk for auth.
When I launch my app, my util functions responsible for fetching things like user or company data will fail and I will get an error notifying me that the app is unable to read a certain property from the data I pull. Then, I will refresh and the server will successfully fetch the data.
Wondering if this is as simple as my connection speed being poor or if my util functions are improperly written. Example functions below
export const getUserByClerkID = async () => {
  const { userId } = await auth()
  //console.log('CLERK USER ID ', userId)
  try {
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: {
        clerkId: userId,
      },
    })
    return user
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching user by clerk ID', error)
  }
}

export const fetchOrgData = async () => {
  const user = await getUserByClerkID()
  console.log('USER WHILE FETCHING ORG DATA', user)
  try {
    const orgData = await prisma.company.findFirst({
      where: {
        employees: {
          some: {
            clerkId: user.clerkId,
          },
        },
      },
      include: {
        employees: true,
        teams: true,
        savedCandidates: true,
        messageThreads: true,
      },
    })

    return orgData
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching org data', error)
  }
}

I've added the try/catch blocks and I added some RLS to my supabase models. When I used planetscale, I didn't encounter this issue, so I am wondering if it might be an issue with the way I setup Supabase in my existing application.

What's the full error you are receiving from Prisma?

Resolved: Created a buffer from the file before saving blob files to vercel blob storage
